# TweetNaCl.js minimal Public-key signatures example

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, tweet-nacl

I am trying to understand how to implement a minimal basic Public-key signature example based on the demo located [here](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/sign), using pure javascript.

My research has not yielded a simple javascript example that I can use to understand its inner workings, and the [documentation](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/README.md#documentation) is over my head at the moment.

I tried looking at the [source code](http://view-source:https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/sign) of the demo, but it is not revealing its secrets.

The library's [examples](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/wiki/Examples) does not have an example for this either.

Cryptography is something very new to me, so any baseline example of how to create their Public-key example with pure javascript in node.js would be greatly appreciated!

Pseudocode-ish:

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl')
let message = "This is my unencrypted message"
let naclPair = nacl.sign.keyPair()
let signedMessage = nacl.sign(message, naclPair.secretKey)
let decrypted = nacl.sign.open(signedMessage, naclPair.publicKey) // is this right?
console.log(decrypted) // should this print the decrypted message?
```

As a side note, I'm more familiar with node.js `require`, than I am with ES6 `import`, if that has any bearing on answers here and could help demonstrate how to use this library.

Comment: Just by looking at the example and the README on their GitHub, it seems right, yes. But note that, when signing a message, it’s not “encrypted”, it’s “signed”. If you want to learn cryptography, I suggest you start with the maths behind it and implement stuff in C. That should have most transparency over the math. Good luck!

Comment: @Victor I appreciate the comment. I am looking for how to use the TweetNaCL.js library with javascript without needing to learn C, as that is why a library exists. I just need the right nudge to get it working.

Comment: Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TweetNaCl.js](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js) is a port to JavaScript of [TweetNaCl](https://cryptojedi.org/papers/tweetnacl-20131229.pdf). TweetNacl in turn is a compact implementation of [NaCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software)), which provides various encryption and signature algorithms essentially based on [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519). There are NaCl-compatible implementations or wrappers for many platforms, so that any of these documentations can be used for an introduction, e.g. the clear documentation of the [Libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org/) fork.

The documentation of TweetNaCl.js also gives a short overview of the functionality: [`nacl.sign(message, secretKey)`](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#naclsignmessage-secretkey) creates a signed message consisting of the 64 bytes signature with attached message. [`nacl.sign.open(signedMessage, publicKey)`](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#naclsignopensignedmessage-publickey) verifies the message using the signature and returns the message if verification is successful. The algorithm used for signing is [Ed25519](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#signatures).

As already noted in the comments, you do not distinguish clearly between encryption (purpose: secrecy) and [signing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (purpose: authentication / integrity). In particular, secrecy of the message is not the purpose of signing. This becomes apparent e.g. when the return of `nacl.sign()` contains the unencrypted message (see code snippet below). However, it is true that encryption with the private key is performed during signing (but not for the purpose of keeping it secret).

The following implementation is a pure JavaScript implementation:

```js
var keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair();
var secretKey  = keyPair.secretKey;
var publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
var msgStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var msg = nacl.util.decodeUTF8(msgStr);
var signature = nacl.sign(msg, secretKey);
var signatureB64 = nacl.util.encodeBase64(signature);
console.log(signatureB64.replace(/(.{64})/g,'$1\n')); // Display signature plus message (Base64 encoded)
var signatureMsgPart = signature.slice(64); 
console.log(nacl.util.encodeUTF8(signatureMsgPart));  // Display message from nacl.sign() return value: signing is not for encryption!
var verifiedMsg = nacl.sign.open(signature, publicKey);
console.log(nacl.util.encodeUTF8(verifiedMsg));       // Display message after successfull verification
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-util@0.15.0/nacl-util.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl@1.0.1/nacl.min.js"></script>
```

and applies the package [tweetnacl-util-js](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-util-js) for encoding.

By the way, in the implementation you posted only the Utf8 encoding/decoding was missing:

```js
let message = "This is my unencrypted message"
let naclPair = nacl.sign.keyPair()
let signedMessage = nacl.sign(nacl.util.decodeUTF8(message), naclPair.secretKey)
let decrypted = nacl.sign.open(signedMessage, naclPair.publicKey) // is this right? -> Yes
console.log(nacl.util.encodeUTF8(decrypted)) // should this print the decrypted message? -> Yes, but the 'verified' message is printed!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl-util@0.15.0/nacl-util.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweetnacl@1.0.1/nacl.min.js"></script>
```

Please see the following links for [public key encryption](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/README.md#public-key-authenticated-encryption-box) and [symmetric encryption](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/README.md#secret-key-authenticated-encryption-secretbox) with TweetNaCl.js. This is about keeping a message secret.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! My intention at this point was only for message integrity.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, using the example page([Public-key signatures](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/sign)) to test the code need to use `nacl.sign.detached(message, secretKey)` not `nacl.sign(msg, secretKey)`

---

reference

[TweetNaCl.js Public-key signatures example err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132331/tweetnacl-js-public-key-signatures-example-err/69132850#69132850)