# TweetNaCl.js Public-key signatures example err

Tags: javascript, cryptography, signature, key-pair, tweet-nacl

I want to use ed25519 to sign my message. And I found TweetNaCl.js which has the [Signatures](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#signatures) method to achieve my goal.

By referencing [TweetNaCl.js minimal Public-key signatures example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761119/tweetnacl-js-minimal-public-key-signatures-example) and official document-[Signatures](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#signatures),
here is my test code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pond-zcvhh?file=/src/App.js).

```
  const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair();
  const secretKey = keyPair.secretKey;
  const publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
  const secretKeyB64 = encodeBase64(secretKey);
  const publicKeyB64 = encodeBase64(publicKey);
  console.log("secretKeyB64", secretKeyB64);
  console.log("publicKeyB64", publicKeyB64);

  const msgStr = "My unencrypted message";
  const msg = decodeUTF8(msgStr);
  const signature = nacl.sign(msg, secretKey);
  const signatureB64 = encodeBase64(signature);
  console.log("signatureB64", signatureB64);
  const verifiedMsg = nacl.sign.open(signature, publicKey);
  console.log(encodeUTF8(verifiedMsg));
```

The `encodeUTF8(verifiedMsg)`'s console log seems no problem and is as same as `msgStr`.

But I notice that when I put the `publicKeyB64`, `signatureB64`, and `msgStr` to the tweetnacl.js' example page([Public-key signatures](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/sign)) to verify it, it responds error `Bad signature length: must be 64 bytes`.

If I put the `secretKeyB64` into the example sign page, and click "Sign", the Signature seems shorter than what I created from Codesandbox's code.

Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 3):

I figure out this problem 20 minutes later... Thanks for the StackOverflow ?!!

I console log the `signature` and find its length is over 64. After I reviewed the  [Signatures](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#signatures), I found another method `nacl.sign.detached(message, secretKey)` and its length was 64!!!

After encodeBase64 and put it to the tweetnacl.js' example page(Public-key signatures) to verify it, it works!!